# RxJS debounceTime(0) causes unit tests failed

Tags: angular, jestjs, rxjs, angular-spectator

Added debounceTime(0) since without it my changes were not reflected to the ui properly, additionally benefit was combineLatest optiomization  but it broke my unit tests.

```
get nativeWindow(): Window {
    return window;
}

private resize$ = fromEvent(this.nativeWindow, 'resize').pipe(
        debounceTime(50),
        map(event => event.target as Window),
        startWith(this.nativeWindow),
        untilDestroyed(this)
    );


protected dimensions$: Observable<{ width: number; height: number }> = combineLatest([this.resize$]).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.elementRef$),
        debounceTime(0),
        map(([, ref]) => ({ width: ref.nativeElement.offsetWidth, height: ref.nativeElement.offsetHeight })),
        filter(dim => dim.width > 0)
    );
```

Example unit test which worked before. I'm using @ngneat/spectator

```
  it('should display cropped image', () => {
                host.setHostInput({
                    assetCrop: {
                        type: 'CROP',
                        x: 100,
                        y: 100,
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200
                    }
                });
                    expect(crop?.backgroundPosition).toBe('-100px -100px');
                    expect(crop?.backgroundSize).toBe('1000px 1000px');
            });
```

I tried with fakeAsync and tick as well as whenStable but no successfully

Comment: You have not provided enough code to debug anything, but you *must* write your test around asynchronous logic if it depends on observables.  If it was passing it was by accident, was never robust, and cannot be expected to behave consistently.

Comment: You're not right because the test reflected crop results correctly before

Comment: Like I said, you can get coincidental behavior, even very consistently, if the scheduler decides it.  You changed the timing and now you are having a problem because you wrote your test wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So after investigating a problem it seems that the problem was without `debounceTime(0)` the stream tried to get dimensions before the resizing process finished. Adding setTimeout made it work but I'm not satisfied with the solution.

```
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.#imageWrapperDimensions$.next({
                width: this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth,
                height: this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight
            });
        });
    }

    private resize$: Observable<{ width: number; height: number }> = this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() =>
        fromEvent(this.window, 'resize').pipe(
            debounceTime(50),
            map(event => event.target as Window),
            startWith(this.window),
            map(() => ({ width: this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth, height: this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight })),
            untilDestroyed(this)
        )
    );

    #imageWrapperDimensions$ = new Subject<{ width: number; height: number }>();

    protected imageWrapperDimensions$: Observable<{ width: number; height: number }> = merge(
        this.resize$,
        this.#imageWrapperDimensions$
    ).pipe(filter(dim => dim.width > 0));
```